# Page Reload Infinite Loop with TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a JS script to automate some work process. What I am trying to have my JS do is first enter the account number and then click on the search button. What this does is populate the account info below the search field. However the issue is that it simply just reloads the page with the populated info. My JS recognizes the page load and starts the process all over and searches the same account number creating an infinite loop. Is there a way I can have my code recognize that the search button has been clicked and we do not have to click it again on the new page load?
I am having the code run on page load and maybe that's not the way to do it? I am using Tampermonkey in chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using jQuery in your script, you might try adding the cookie plugin, and then you can set a cookie named 'currentAccount' (or whatever) with the account number.  Then when a new page loads, read that cookie and if the cookie and the current account number match, don't bother entering it and clicking search.  Then if you go to a different account number, it will fire, but it won't fire again on the page that loads from the initial search.  But I haven't played with tampermonkey, so I don't know if it can be done or not.

Comment: Share some code, so we can provide more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a variable, it may loop itself constantly. Make sure the variable is not always active.